# How to handle Web Text if its changing the position on every run?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

Suppose, 
After login on web page, the text "WELCOME" is showing in center, but in a next run it will be in top-right corner(position is unpredictable after every run.) So how to verify that text in Selenium Web-driver script?

Comment: Please add the html for the text

Comment: Withe the changing position if 'id' or 'name' attribute is not changing, then you can always verify the text no matter the position. We can help you further if you can paste the html code for the WELCOME text by viewing the page source.

Comment: As Guy and HemChe wrote you should pase html code. You can also verify if "WELCOME" text is present in your page, (something like this, I have not compiled it):`bool isWelcomePresent = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText.contains("WELCOME");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xpath` and search for the text `WELCOME`, if it doesn't have a unique id name class etc... If it has an unique identifier you are on easy street. Whatever container like a div span it is in replace * with that.

```
//*[.='WELCOME']
```

or

```
//*[text()='WELCOME']
```

if `driver.findElements(By.xpath)` has a size equal to 1 it works.

Comment: @Nikil If the answer solved your issue can you accept it. Thanks